# M-1 rifle ammo and grenade invasion ration

Tags: military

How many rounds did US Army infantry carry on a beach landing?  One belt of 10, 8 round clips?  two belts?  How many grenades?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is a nice question but is a little over broad.  Which time period are you talking about and which theatres of war?

Comment: I'm guessing this question about D-day invasions, is that correct?

Comment: And which exact landing, which unit? A UDT trooper would carry less as he'd not be expected to be there long, and was carrying other things (like demolition charges). An infantryman storming a beach would carry another load from a mortar crewman who'd also be carrying other equipment. A medic carries something else again. From speaking with friends who've been soldiers in different eras, most seem to carry a load of no more than 100 rounds, and often less, as a general rule of thumb throughout the decades. So 10 clips sounds reasonable as an upper limit.

Answer (score 3):

The basic low-level tactical infantry unit in World War II was the [Rifle Squad](http://www.bayonetstrength.150m.com/Tactics/Formations/rifle_squad.htm), and it is more valuable to think in terms of the ammunition carried by such a squad. The typical (rifle and pistol) rounds carried by a Rifle Squad of 8-10 men is there listed as 1500-1600 rounds, which is 150-200 rounds per man.

Comment: how about grenades?